# How do I specify “the start of today” in a specific time zone?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a “timestamp with time zone” column. I would like to find all of the rows whose timestamp is earlier than today, where “today” is determined in a specific time zone.

I know how to use `at time zone` to interpret a literal timestamp as being in some particular time zone, and I know how to use `date_trunc` to get the beginning of this day. But I’m not sure how to combine them to get what I need. I tried

```
select date_trunc('day', current_date at time zone 'cst');
```

which gave me “2015-03-16 00:00:00”, but it’s unclear to me what time zone is used for this result (or whether it has one at all). How can I select the beginning of the current day according to a specific time zone?

Comment: Given that my current day is 2015-03-17, how would you expect me to answer the question, "What is the beginning of the current day in UTC?" One possibility is "2015-03-16 20:00:00-04". Another is "2015-03-17 00:00:00-04". Look hard at this: `select current_date as today, current_date::timestamp as beg_of_today, current_date::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' as beg_of_today_utc,  current_date + time '00:00:00' at time zone 'UTC';`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It helped me to reframe the question as follows: what are the current date and time in the Central time zone? Then, what I want is the midnight at the beginning of that day [in the Central time zone]. I found that I could write this as

```
current_date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'cst'
```

Comment: That answer was very helpful only want to add that this is a complete solution that doesn't need `date_trunc`.   And it's equivalent to the more verbose `select date_trunc('day', current_date)::timestamp at time zone 'cst';

Answer (score 1):

This example may be useful to understand PostgreSQL timezone functionality:

```
SELECT now()            as utc_now, -- 2021-08-29 11:38:08.552247 +00:00
       pg_typeof(now()) as type_of_utc_now, -- timestamp with time zone

       tehran_local_now, -- 2021-08-29 16:08:08.552247
       pg_typeof(tehran_local_now), -- timestamp without time zone

       utc_calculated_from_tehran_local_now, -- 2021-08-29 11:38:08.552247 +00:00
       pg_typeof(utc_calculated_from_tehran_local_now), -- timestamp with time zone

       tehran_local_start_of_today, -- 2021-08-29 00:00:00.000000
       pg_typeof(tehran_local_start_of_today), -- timestamp without time zone

       utc_start_of_today_at_tehran_timezone, -- 2021-08-28 19:30:00.000000 +00:00
       pg_typeof(utc_start_of_today_at_tehran_timezone) -- timestamp with time zone

FROM (SELECT now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran' as tehran_local_now) as tln
         CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT (now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran') at time zone 'Asia/Tehran' as utc_calculated_from_tehran_local_now) as ucftln
         CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT date_trunc('day', now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran') as tehran_local_start_of_today) as tlsot
         CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT date_trunc('day', now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran') at time zone
             'Asia/Tehran' as utc_start_of_today_at_tehran_timezone) as usotatt;
```

The PostgreSQL function `now()` (column `utc_now`) returns the current timestamp in UTC without any timezone. Its type is `timestamp with time zone`. Its Java equivalent is  `Instant.now()`.

When you use `now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran'` (column `tehran_local_now`) it indicates the current date-time in Tehran local. Its type is `timestamp without time zone`. Its Java equivalent is:

```java
Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tehran")).toLocalDateTime()
```

When you use `date_trunc('day', now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran')` (column `tehran_local_start_of_today`) it indicates the start of today in Tehran local. Its type is `timestamp without time zone`. Its Java equivalent is:

```java
Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tehran")).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
```

When you use `date_trunc('day', now() at time zone 'Asia/Tehran') at time zone 'Asia/Tehran'` (column `utc_start_of_today_at_tehran_timezone`) it indicates the start of today in Tehran timezone (not local). Its type is `timestamp with time zone`. You may need this one. Its Java equivalent is:

```java
Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tehran")).truncatedTo(DAYS).toInstant()
```