# Postgresql date_trunc with time zone shifts zone by 1 hr

Tags: postgresql, timezone, postgresql-9.4

we are using Postgresql 9.4 and i noticed a strange behavior when using date_trunc. The time zone in result is shifted by 1hr:

```
select date_trunc('year','2016-08-05 04:01:58.372486-05'::timestamp with time zone);
       date_trunc
------------------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00-06
```

There is no such behavior when truncating to for example day:

```
select date_trunc('day','2016-08-05 04:01:58.372486-05'::timestamp with time zone);
       date_trunc
------------------------
2016-08-05 00:00:00-05
```

Is this expected behavior? If so what is the logic behind that?

Comment: That's most probably because daylight saving time rules: your current timezone setting's offset is shifted between `2016-08-05` and `2016-01-01`

Comment: Oh. I didn't thought about that. You are right. Additionally I noticed that date_trunk is always truncating to the time zone which is set on postgres it doesn't take into account the time zone of timestamp. Example: `select date_trunc('year','2016-08-05 04:01:58.372486-05'::timestamp with time zone); => 2016-01-01 00:00:00+02`

Comment: Now, that is stange ... but after browsing the docs, it seems `date_trunc` should only accept `timestamp`s, not `timestamp with time zone`s (actually, it should convert those automatically by cutting the time zone off) and return `timestamp`s. But instead, I found a `date_trunc(text, timestamp with time zone) returns timestamp with time zone` definition in the `pg_catalog` (the default schema), which is not mentioned in the docs at all.

Comment: So my point is, this seems like it is an undocumented feature, so end-users shouldn't rely on it. If you want a solution, which is future-proof, you should either cast values to `timestamp (without time zone)`, or use the `ts AT TIME ZONE tz` expression before calling `date_trunc`.

Comment: Also found [this related thread on Postgres' mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20041101220039.0E16B3A46CD%40svr1.postgresql.org)

Comment: Yes, the documentation is misleading. I guess it means "type `timestamp`, be it with or without time zone". In `psql` you can say `\df date_trunc` to see the truth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `date_trunc(text, timestamptz)` variant seems a bit under-documented, so here are my findings:

1) below the `day` precision (first parameter) the time zone **offset** of the result is always the same as the second parameters' offset.

2) at or above `day` precision, the time zone **offset** is recalculated, according to the current `TimeZone` configuration parameter (which [can be set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) with `set time zone '...'` or `set TimeZone to '...'`). The recalculated offset is always the same as it would be on that exact time-instant with the **same** `TimeZone` configuration parameter in effect. So, f.ex. when the `TimeZone` parameter **contains DST** information, then the offset is aligned accordingly. However, when the actual `TimeZone` parameter does not contain DST informations (such as a fix offset), the result's time zone offset is untouched.

All-in-all, the `date_trunc(text, timestamptz)` function can be simulated with the `date_trunc(text, timestamp)` variant and the `at time zone` operator**s**:

```
date_trunc('month', tstz)
```

should be equivalent to:

```
date_trunc('month', tstz at time zone current_setting('TimeZone')) at time zone current_setting('TimeZone'))
```

At least, that's what I thought. As it turned out, there are some `TimeZone` configuration settings, which are problematic. Because:

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - A **full time zone name**, for example `America/New_York`. The recognized time zone names are listed in the `pg_timezone_names` view (see Section 50.80). PostgreSQL uses the widely-used IANA time zone data for this purpose, so the same time zone names are also recognized by much other software.
> - A **time zone abbreviation**, for example `PST`. Such a specification merely defines a particular offset from `UTC`, in contrast to full time zone names which can imply a set of daylight savings transition-date rules as well. The recognized abbreviations are listed in the `pg_timezone_abbrevs` view (see Section 50.79). You cannot set the configuration parameters `TimeZone` or `log_timezone` to a time zone abbreviation, but you can use abbreviations in date/time input values and with the AT TIME ZONE operator.

(The third is the fix offset, or its POSIX form, but that's not important here).

As you can see, **abbreviations** cannot be set to `TimeZone`. But there are some abbreviations, which is also considered a **full time zone name**, f.ex. `CET`. Thus, `set time zone 'CET'` will succeed, but will actually use `CEST` in the summer time. But `at time zone 'CET'` will always refer to the **abbreviation**, which is a fixed offset from `UTC` (and never `CEST`, for that one can use `at time zone 'CEST'`; but `set time zone 'CEST'` is invalid).

Here is a full list of time zone settings, which has incompatible meanings when they are used in `set time zone` vs. when they are used in `at time zone` (as of 9.6):

```
CET
EET
MET
WET
```

With the following script, you can check for your version:

```
create or replace function incompatible_tz_settings()
  returns setof text
  language plpgsql
as $func$
declare
  cur cursor for select name from pg_timezone_names;
begin
  for rec IN cur loop
    declare
      r pg_timezone_names;
    begin
      r := rec;
      execute format('set time zone %L', (r).name);
      if exists(select 1
                from   generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '12 months', current_timestamp + interval '12 months', interval '1 month') tstz
                where  date_trunc('month', tstz) <> date_trunc('month', tstz at time zone (r).name) at time zone (r).name) then
        return next (r).name;
      end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end
$func$;
```

http://rextester.com/GBL17756

Comment: There is indeed a special case for `timestamptz_trunc` (and not for `timestamp_trunc`) and finer than day precision: look for `redotz` in https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c

Answer (score 5):

It is expected to have two variants of `date_trunc`: one for `timestamp` and one for `timestamptz`, because [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) says:

> All the functions and operators described below that take time or
>   timestamp inputs actually come in two variants: one that takes time
>   with time zone or timestamp with time zone, and one that takes time
>   without time zone or timestamp without time zone. For brevity, these
>   variants are not shown separately.

Should you want to better understand timestamp and timestamptz, read first [the great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#answer-9576170).

Then about `date_trunc`. According to my experiments and interpretation of various SO answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102110/how-do-i-specify-the-start-of-today-in-a-specific-time-zone)), everything behaves as if, when receiving a timestamptz, `date_trunc` first converts it to a timestamp. This conversion returns a timestamp in local time. Then truncation is performed: keep only the date and drop the hours/min/seconds.

To avoid this conversion (thanks pozs), provide a timestamp (not timestamptz) to date_trunc:

```
date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMPTZ '2001-07-16 23:38:40Z' at time zone 'UTC')
```

the part `at time zone 'UTC'` says "convert this timestamptz to a timestamp in UTC time" (the hour isn't affected by this conversion). Then date_trunc returns `2001-07-16 00:00:00`.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't noticed that in the docs, but it makes sense.